# What is a code block in the middle of apparently nothing doing on a .c file?

Tags: c

What does this code means? Specifically, what are the curly braces doing? They're not in the middle of a function.

```
yyerror(s) char * s;

{
    fputs(s,stderr), putc('\n',stderr);
}
```

Comment: It's an old style function definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like K&R syntax.  In standard C, it would look like:

```
int yyerror(char *s)
{
    fputs(s,stderr), putc('\n',stderr);
}
```

The comma operator in the function body is really a no-op in this case, too.  You could easily replace it with a semicolon and get this more familiar looking (and equivalent) code:

```
int yyerror(char *s)
{
    fputs(s,stderr);
    putc('\n',stderr);
}
```

Note that by default this function is assumed to return `int` since the return type wasn't specified, but the function doesn't contain a `return` statement.  That means you shouldn't rely on the return value of this function anywhere in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Old style function declaration.

Then in the function body:

```
fputs(s,stderr), putc('\n',stderr);
```

is equivalent to

```
fputs(s,stderr); putc('\n',stderr);
```